# How to use Mockito to mock java stream and filter operation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, java-stream

I've been searching and banging my head on this for a while, and was wondering if anyone out here had any idea how to mock, or if it's even possible to mock this code.

Here's the code. I need to mock 'programs' and have it return a designated 'Program' object:

```
private Program getProgramFromClient(Client client) {
    return programs.stream().filter(
            program -> program.getProgramCode()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(client.getProgramCode()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
}
```

I'm presently using the @Mock annotations on these objects as follows:

```
@Mock
private Program program;

@Mock
private List<Program> programs;
```

Then in the test class I have the following...

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {

   ...

   programs = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then in the test method I have this:

```
when(programs.stream().filter(any()).collect(any())).thenReturn(programs);
when(programs.get(any())).thenReturn(program);
```

When I run the test, I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Which is referring to this line:

```
when(programs.stream().filter(any()).collect(any())).thenReturn(programs);
```

When I click the error, the cursor moves to the beginning of 'filter', so it looks like it's saying programs is empty, which I suppose is true, but I'm (trying) to mock it.
Do I need to make it an un-mocked list?
i.e. a real list with the program added?
I think I tried this earlier and still ran into trouble, but If someone suggests it again, I can re-try.

The following is also part of the error message, but my feeble and burnt brain is having trouble understanding exactly what this all means at the moment:

```
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

As always, any and all help is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Don't go down the mocking path. List is trivial to construct. Test your method with a real List with a few known Programs. Think of edge cases - what if no program matches your client. And lastly - think how to improve implementation: is collecting to List necessary to get first element? Maybe change API to return Optional?

Comment: Don't mock collections or streams.  There's never a good reason to.

Comment: See also Mockito’s documentation: [Don't mock a type you don't own!](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own), not a hard rule but I think the 3rd bullet applies here: “_might be complex and require a lot of mocks to even work properly_”. In this case I would just use real lists, typically `Arrays.asList(test values)`. If `Program` is a POJO I wouldn’t mock it either – [Don't mock value objects](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-value-objects) from the same documentation page.

Comment: OK, thanks guys!